# What is the best structure in HDF5 for a sensor signal?

Tags: hdf5

I have a project in which I want to export measured sensor signals into a HDF5 file.

The data I have consists of time,value pairs per sensor. The sensor data is sparse, meaning each sensor sends its data at different times and intervals. So there can be a sensor which sends data each second, as well as a sensor which sends data each minute. All data is 64 bit floating point for now.

What is the best format for this? Should I create a Nx2 signal and store it in a group called sensors and store the timestamp and value next to eachother? Or should I create a group per sensor and store the values and timestamps in seperate arrays?

I'm looking for best practices here. I would like to be able to plot the signals easily in python.

In case anyone is wondering what I'm doing, this is the project in question: https://github.com/windelbouwman/lognplot

Comment: Did you find a workable solution for this?

Comment: Currently I'm using a 2xN f64 array with timestamps in seconds since epoch. There is a problem with time resolution here, so this is my current solution.